# Laravel Dusk Javascript Confirm()

Tags: javascript, laravel, confirm, laravel-dusk

In my form, in order to submit, I need to press the OK button in a Javascript confirm() popup. How can I confirm in Laravel Dusk so that I can automate the submission of the form for testing purposes?

[image: Image of the Confirm]

Comment: Here are the official Dusk docs about it: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/dusk#javascript-dialogs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$browser->dismissDialog() = press Cancel (if confirmation)
$browser->acceptDialog() = press OK
$browser->assertDialogOpened('Text in dialog'); = check dialog exist with text specified.
```

Good luck